# How does DOM detect an existing element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#test').click(function () {
  $('body').append($('<button>').prop('id', 'demo').text('Click me'))
});

$('#demo').click(function () {
  alert('Hello world!')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Append</button>
```

I've checked in `Console log`, no error was found. I think something may be: Element with id `demo` does not exist, so no message would throw when clicking on it.

Is there any way to set new element (created by jQuery syntax) detects the event (onclick)?

I don't want to use this way:

```
var btnClick = function () {
  alert('Hello world!')
};

$('#test').click(function () {
  $('body').append($('<button>').prop('id', 'demo')
                                .attr('onclick', 'btnClick()').text('Click me'))
});
```

Comment: The id is the same for all the new buttons, ids must be unique. Use class instead.

Comment: @Ness Rosales is right. Also, you can use the [`jQuery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to attach a click handler to all your buttons

Comment: Why don't you want to use the way that you say you don't want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use event delegation **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** :

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('body').on('click', '#demo', function () {
     alert('Hello world!')
})
```

Hope this helps.